# How to make a statement in Python without calculating it?

Tags: python

So I'm doing homework online for Python and I need help figuring out how to make an arithmetic statement without it calculating the expression. Every time I try to do that, it keeps messing it up by solving it.

Here is the statement I need to translate into Python code:
"4+5 is 9"

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: What is wrong with calculating the expression?

Comment: I tried: `print(user_num + user_num2 , 'is' , sum)` but I keep getting `9 is <built-in function sum>`

Comment: Try `print(user_num + user_num2 , 'is' , sum((user_num, user_num2)))`

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `print()` command in Python, it outputs your string (the one you pass as a parameter) verbatim - that is, exactly as you originally typed it.

Therefore:

```
print("4+5 is 9") #prints 4+5 is 9
print(4+5, "is 9") #prints 9 is 9
```

If you want to output the two variables, you may try `print(user_num, '+', user_num2, 'is', sum)`

Answer (score 0):

either

```
a = 4
b = 5
c = a + b

output = a + " + " + b + " = " + c
print(output)
```

or

```
a = 4
b = 5
c = a + b

output = "{}+{}={}".format(a, b, c)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_num = 4
user_num2 = 5
sum = user_num + user_num2
print('{} + {} is {}'.format(user_num, user_num2, sum))
```

Comment: I know you're just copying the code posted for the question, but don't use the name of a built-in function like `sum` as a variable name.